# What's the relationship between ssh console and bash?

Tags: bash, ssh, console

This is somewhat a Grandma question, but nevertheless, I can't really figure it out.

It's the following: I log in to a remote machine via ssh. There (for example!) I try to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH appropriately. This is often done with `export` but on the console I get from ssh, `export` leads to `"Command not found"`. I type then `bash` and now I can use export.

On the other hand, I don't need to enter the bash terminal to execute sh-scripts and makefiles which contain for example the `export` command but can do it right from the console I get when entering via ssh.

I would be glad if someone could explain me this in a few words! Or how can I find out more?

Comment: As kidmose says, this has nothing to do with ssh. If you could login directly to the server (i.e., by going to its physical console), you would get the same interface you are seeing now. You can run scripts and Makefiles because they, internally, invoke `bash` (or at least `/bin/sh`, which is a predecessor of `bash` and is very similar to it). If you look at the scripts that you are using, you'll probably notice that they begin with `#!/bin/sh` or (rarely) `#!/bin/bash`. The `make` program is probably hard-coded to use `/bin/sh`, although it may be possible to override this in a Makefile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bash is a shell, replacing sh, which was common before.

SSH is a protocol for secure connections.

From bash(a shell on you machine) you can run the program ssh to securely communicate with a shell on another machine. 
That shell might not be bash, but if bash is available you can enter a bash shell (within the other shell) by typing "bash" and then you can use export (which I think is a part of bash)

Comment: But how do I have to understand this: The shell I get when entering via ssh, this is something LIKE bash or is it more something UNDERLYING bash? ($SHELL says that I have tcsh)

Comment: tcsh is an alternative to bash. They serve the same purpose, but in somewhat different ways.
The admin of your remote server presumably figured that tcsh would server you better, but as you've found you can just open up bash instead.

Comment: @Michael: If you’re more comfortable with bash, and it’s available, you may as well use it. (If you type `exec bash`, you won’t need to `exit` twice when you’re done.) But, in case you want to learn more about `tcsh`, you can look at its `man` page, or look for documentation on `csh`, a.k.a. “the C shell” (`tcsh` is an evolved version of `csh`). In particular (for example), to set an environment variable, use `setenv (variable) (value)` (note: no `=`) rather than `export (variable)=(value)`.

Comment: @kidmose, this might be nitpicky, but you don't have to start in a bash shell. You can open a SSH connection from Putty in Windows without an initial bash shell.

Comment: One question remains: Is there something like a very basic shell which underlays all the other shells? Or asked the other way around: How do shells like bash and tcsh communicate with the Linux system? Directly with system calls?

Comment: And one more: Why can make use export when called in tcsh? Does make forward the commands to bash by default?

Comment: @Adam: you're right :)
You'd have to read up on linux and the os architecture. 
As for make: Is export a make command? Again, read a tut or some doc :)

Comment: @Michael, if no shell is specified, `make` uses `/bin/sh`, see [this page](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html).

Comment: @Michael, the bash shell (as an example) communicates directly with the kernel in the form of system calls and signals, there's no middleman at that point, just lots of C code. If you have any additional questions, rather than posting a comment, start a new question.